# How to only add layers on map but prevent to request rendering (visible false is not working)

Tags: openlayers, visibility, layer

I'm facing an issue for several days now.
I have an OpenLayers map with several WMS image or tile layers. Most of them are set to "visible=false", and they are indeed hidden on the map. But when I check the network queries, image(s) are generated anyway from the map server (GeoServer in my case).

Is there something else to do when setting a layer "visible=false" so that it will really not be loaded with the map ? And only when I decide to set it back "visible=true" ?

I also use LayerSwitcher on UI to manage layers visibility.

Many thanks.